Distribution of number of nonzero elements in binary matrix when forming submatrix
I have a binary matrix (all elements are $0$ or $1$)  $A \in \mathcal{R}^{K\times L}  $ with some rules.
$A = \mathbf{1}_{C \times R}\bigotimes \mathbf{I}_{\frac{K}{C}\times \frac{L}{R}}  $
Example of matrix $A$ : ($K=6 , L=4, C=3, R=2$)
\begin{equation*}
A =
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
   1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation*}
Each column and row  of matrix $A$ has $C$ and $R$ ones, respectively.
I define a submatrix $B$ that is formed by selecting rows from matrix $A$.
Each row of $A$ is chosen as an independent trial of the probability $p=\frac{K_a }{K} \,(K_a<K)$.
The random variable $T_j\,\,(j=1,...,L)$ is the number of $1$s in $j$-th column of matrix $B$.
Example of matrix $B$ : (first and third rows of $A$ are selected)
\begin{equation*}
B =
   \begin{bmatrix} 
   1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   1 & 0 & 1 & 0  \\
   \end{bmatrix} , (T_1 = 2, T_2 =0, T_3 = 2, T_4 =0)
\end{equation*}
Can i get distribution of the random variable $T_j$?
Or, is there any better random variable that represent the number of nonzero elements of matrix $B$ ?
Intuitively, the distribution of $T_j$ is $B(C, p)$.
However, we have to consider if a row is selected in $A$, it affects the number of 1s in several columns of $B$.
Thank you in advance for your response.
